# In how many different ways can 12 people order 3 different drinks, and what's the probability that each gets the one he ordered?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

So I'm new to probability and combinatorics and I've got this problem, that seems simple enough, but I can't quite get my head around it.

At a party, there are 12 students and 3 sorts of drinks. punch, wine and brandy.

1. They're about to run out of drinks, so they send one of them to bring them more drinks. How many different ways could the order be?

Well basically I thought about this a little bit, and here the order doesn't matter as long as the correct drinks are brought, and repetion is allowed. So I just used the formula:

${n+k-1 \choose n - 1} = {3 + 12 -1 \choose 3 - 1} = {14 \choose 2}$ = $91$ different possibilities.

First of all, is that correct?

second part of the question is where I'm having a bit of trouble... it goes like this:

The students order 8x wine, 2x punch, 2x brandy. Unfortunately, the cups are not see-through and each has to randomally pick up a cup. What is the probability that each student gets the correct cup he ordered?

My thinking behind this was that when a student takes a cup, at first the probability to get a wine is 8/12, to get punch it's 2/12 and brandy is 2/12. However, depending on the outcome of the first student, all of those probabilities would change. And we have 12! ways in which the students can approach the cups, so then I started thinking a bit differently... I thought, what if the order that the cups are taken, corresponds with just the one correct order that the students can pick up their cups so that each gets his own?

I thought of the order of the drinks as the number of different linear combinations, which can be calculated as $$\frac{12!}{8!2!2!} = 2970$$ and the probability that it is the correct order would be $\frac{1}{2970}$ and then we multiply that by the probability that the students take their cups in the correct order which I think would be $\frac{1}{12!}$

So the final answer would be: $$\frac{1}{2970} \times \frac{1}{12!} = 7.02 \times 10^{-13}$$

Is this even remotely correct? As I said I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is correct.

For the second part, the right answer is just $\frac{1}{2970}$ (no need to divide by $12!$ again). This is because there are $12!$ different ways of assigning glasses to students, but $8!2!2!$ ways of assigning them so that every student gets the right sort of drink (there are $8!$ different ways to arrange the wines between the wine-drinking students, for each of these there are $2!$ ways to arrange the punches between the punch-drinkers and $2!$ ways to arrange the brandies).

Since there are $8!2!2!$ successful ways and $12!$ total ways (all of which are equally likely), the probability of success is $\frac{8!2!2!}{12!}$.